# Calling php with python subprocess.call generates php permissions errors

Tags: php, python, codeception

Trying to run php tests with python script.
Using codeception framework, which is successfully works when i'm executing it manually in terminal. But it generates permission issues when i'm trying to call it with subprocess.call like that

```
subprocess.call(['vendor/bin/codecept', 'run'])
```

Errors like

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/root/opt/testing/vendor/bin/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /root/opt/testing/vendor/bin/codecept on line 7 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/root/opt/testing/vendor/bin/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /root/opt/testing/vendor/bin/codecept on line 7
```

Can't find the reason why. Changed all permissions to chmod a+x but still no results.

Looks like it definitely something with python.

Comment: What happens when you chmod -R 777?

Comment: Why is that include path going to /usr/share/php? Where is that comming from? It looks like it's searching for the composer autoloader and searching in the wrong directory?

Comment: Tried chmod -R 777 and that didn't help. Have no idea about Include path, but autoload.php in require_once checked from proper dir.